# Can I somehow get a backtrace of a message in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration

When, for example, an exception occurres in the middle of a spring integration flow, is there any way to get a path the message have traveled before the crash happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message tracks its path only if `@EnableMessageHistory` is switched on.

Independently of error handling, Spring Integration always wraps any exception to the `MessagingException` which has `failedMessage` property.

Getting that message and analizing its `MessageHistory.HEADER_NAME` you get the path before an exception.

Comment: I checked out @EnableMessageHistory. It is available from version 4.0. Do I have any options with the version 2.2.4?

Comment: I gues <int:message-history/> is what I need.